# cannot display data on highchart js

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to display data from MySQL database to highchart. When I do `print_r` the data, it can display the array as well, but when I try to display them to the chart, it's not working. here's my code:

**controller:**

```
    $lokasi = $this->Objekwisata_m->getLokasi();
    $jumlahSad = array();       
    $temp = 0;


    foreach ($lokasi as $lok ) {

        $sad = $this->Objekwisata_m->getSad($lok['id_lokasi']);
        $jumlahSad[$temp] = count($sad);
        $temp++;

    }

    $data['jumlahSad'] = $jumlahSad;
    $data['lokasi'] = $this->Objekwisata_m->getLokasi();

    $this->load->view('objek_wisata_v', $data);
```

**model**

```
public function getSad($id_lokasi){
    $this->db->select('t.result');
    $this->db->from('tbl_testimoni t');
    $this->db->join('tbl_master_lokasi l', 't.id_lokasi = l.id_lokasi', 'left');
    $this->db->where("t.result", "'sad'");
    $this->db->where("t.id_lokasi = '".$id_lokasi."'");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**highchart.js**

```
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Grafik Kepuasan Pengunjung KRB'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [<?php foreach($lokasi as $lok){
            echo "'".$lok['nama_lokasi']."',";
        }?>],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'percents'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sad',
        data: [<?php foreach($jumlahSad as $s){
            echo "'".$s."',";
        }?>]
    }, {
        name: 'Happy',
        data: [<?php foreach($jumlahHappy as $h){
            echo "'".$h."',";
        }?>]
    }, {
        name: 'Disgust',
        data: [<?php foreach($jumlahDisgust as $d){
            echo "'".$d."',";
        }?>]
    }]
});

</script>
```

Comment: What does your browser developer console say when the page loads in? If highcharts is bailing, there will be errors there. Also, look at the raw html source and see if the data you are injecting with php looks correct. Might help if you paste an example from your html output as well, specifically the part on `xAxis: { categories: ...` as that might be where things are going bad (you should json_encode data to cover escaping)

Comment: If you say, it's not working, what have you tried instead? `var_dump` should not be used to echo variables in a specific format, this is better done with `json_encode` or self-written logic

Comment: On a side note, you really don't need to do `$jumlahSad[$temp] = count($sad); $temp++;` ... just do `$jumlahSad[] = count($sad);` and it adds sequentially during that loop.